# Detect IBeam cursor

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cursor

Is there a way for detect IBeam cursors on windows from c++ code?
I wonder is it even possible, for example just the MS Word has several IBeam like cursor (eg. text near or below the IBeam).

Thanks,
Abe

Comment: Why would you want this? The exact cursor shape is really the responsibility of the window it's over. If it's your own window, you know already; if it's someone elses, you shouldn't care.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect the position of the I-beam cursor within a text line?

Comment: Nope, i want to detect the type of the cursor.

Comment: Why i shouldn't care in other windows?
That is the point of my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two ways you can go about this, the easier way requires Vista.  Both start with calling [GetCusorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389.aspx).  You can take the HCURSOR you get from that and pass it into [GetIconInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648071.aspx) on Vista or [GetIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648070.aspx) on XP, casting it to a HICON.  The Ex version includes the resource name which you can search for the word "beam" or other hints about what it might be.  For the older version you have to do image analysis on the HBITMAP mask.  Since you are looking for the type of cursor, this might not be too hard.  Or it could be really difficult, I have never tried anything like this.